# How to sort values like this manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have table like this

```
Province            Country       Date      infected
New South Wales    Australia    1/22/20        12
Victoria           Australia    1/22/20        10
British Columbia   Canada       1/22/20         5
                   USA          1/22/20         7
New South Wales    Australia    1/23/20         6
Victoria           Australia    1/23/20         2
British Columbia   Canada       1/23/20         1
                   USA          1/23/20         10
```

Now I want to convert that table into like this

```
Province            Country       Date      infected
New South Wales    Australia    1/22/20        12
                                1/23/20         6
Victoria           Australia    1/22/20        10
                                1/23/20         2
British Columbia   Canada       1/22/20         5
                                1/23/20         1    
                   USA          1/22/20         7 
                                1/23/20         10
```

I have tried `df.sort_values('Date')` but no luck.

How can I implement such kind of table?

Comment: I believe you have already implemented one ```groupby```, right? Try after your groupby to add```.sort_values(['Province', 'Country', 'Date'])```

Comment: @Newbielp it works but country and province repeated with date

Comment: Then, quick and dirty solution could be to add after sorting this ```.drop(['Province', 'Country'], axis=1)```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need that column values.

Comment: What's the sorting order between date and infected for a particular province in a country?

Comment: @ Kalana, I think your INITIAL ```groupby``` has a problem... try to grouby by two colulmns not just Province, which seems like what you have done. Try to ```groupby(['Province', 'Country'])``` and then whatever else you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Python rookie, but let me think along (I'm sure this can be done neater).

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.groupby(['Province', 'Country', 'Date']).sum()
```

This gave me:

```
Province         Country   Date     infected
British Columbia Canada    1/22/20         5
                           1/23/20         1
                 USA       1/22/20         7
                           1/23/20        10
New South Wales  Australia 1/22/20        12
                           1/23/20         6
Victoria         Australia 1/22/20        10
                           1/23/20         2
```

---

I kind of anticipated you have `NaN` values in the empty places (at least it's what I had importing the dataframe). I changed all these `NaN` to values from the index above them.

Then a `groupby` gave me the result above. Not sure if this is what you were after, but maybe it sparked some ideas =)

Comment: When I am trying to export that data-frame as csv it didn't give me 'Province', 'Country', 'Date' columns

Answer (score 1):

```
dict = {"Province": ["New South Wales", "Victoria", "British Columbia", "", "New South Wales", "Victoria", "British Columbia", ""],
       "Country": ["Australia", "Australia", "Canada", "USA", "Australia", "Australia", "Canada", "USA"],
       "Date": ["1/22/20", "1/22/20", "1/22/20", "1/22/20", "1/23/20", "1/23/20", "1/23/20", "1/23/20"],
       "infected": [12, 10, 6, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5] }

import pandas as pd
brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(brics)

df = brics.set_index(['Country', 'Province', 'Date']).sort_values(['Country', 'Province', 'Date']) 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Province    Country     Date  infected
0   New South Wales  Australia  1/22/20        12
1          Victoria  Australia  1/22/20        10
2  British Columbia     Canada  1/22/20         6
3                          USA  1/22/20         5
4   New South Wales  Australia  1/23/20         2
5          Victoria  Australia  1/23/20         3
6  British Columbia     Canada  1/23/20         4
7                          USA  1/23/20         5
                                    infected
Country   Province         Date
Australia New South Wales  1/22/20        12
                           1/23/20         2
          Victoria         1/22/20        10
                           1/23/20         3
Canada    British Columbia 1/22/20         6
                           1/23/20         4
USA                        1/22/20         5
                           1/23/20         5
```

Comment: Looking at the example of USA I believe it is sorted by Date.

Comment: @ ranka47, actually it is the other way, first Province, then Country to look alike the given output: ```df.set_index(['Province', 'Country', 'Date']).sort_values(['Province', 'Country', 'Date'])```